# Is there a way to enable underpromotions using chess.js?

Tags: javascript, chess

```
var move = game.move({
    from: source,
    to: target,
    promotion: 'q' 
})
```

It is suggested in one of the issues that in order to decide promotion, one simply can change the above code to

```
var move = game.move({
    from: source,
    to: target,
    promotion: 'desired piece' 
})
```

I tried various methods, including

```
promotion: 'q||n'
```

and

```
promotion: 'q'
promotion: 'n'
```

When it comes to giving players the free choice to underpromote, I cannot find a way to do so. Is there such a way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change the promotion piece type:

```
promotion: 'r' // For rook
promotion: 'b' // For bishop
promotion: 'n' // For knight
```

If you want a way for the user to decide which piece he/she wants, you need to create an interface for that, e.g a popup window with buttons. Then you can call `game.move({...})` with the desired piece character set for `promotion`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-chessboard library with chess.js, you can use `onPieceDrop={onDrop}`

`<Chessboard position={fen} onPieceDrop={onDrop} />`

Then, your code can look something like this:

```js
const onDrop = (source: string, target: string, piece: string) => {
    try {
      const move = game.move({
        from: source,
        to: target,
        promotion: piece.slice(-1).toLowerCase(),
      });
        updateStatus();
        return true;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return false;
    }
  };
```